# Is it okay to use a footer tag in an overlay?

Tags: html, css

Is it okay to use an HTML5  tag in an overlay?

Could it clash with any other  tags, which maybe getting used in an application?

Thanks!

Comment: i think its personal preference, "Could it clash with any other tags, which maybe getting used in an application" if you do not mix up the css or any other code, No it will not overlap, if you missed something in the css then Yes it will clash with something

Comment: Okay great, I've given it its own class anyway, so I think it will be fine!